# do we need to include return types for javascript methods

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

I have a doubt with return types of Javascript methods. I have seen some static methods which doesn't contain any clue about return types but return some texts as strings. Please explain:

```
      <script>  
        class Test{  
          static display(){  //This doesn't include return type 
           return "static method is invoked"  
          }  
        }  
        document.writeln(Test.display());  
      </script>
```

Comment: javascript is dynamically typed

Comment: You may notice that JavaScript has absolutely no type annotation whatsoever…

Answer (score 3):

No you don't - and I'm pretty sure it's impossible in pure JS. You can do it in TypeScript, and some other languages support it natively (Swift), but you don't (and can't IIRC) in JavaScript.

If you wish to use TypeScript it would look like:

```
static display(): string {...}
```

Comment: ...although the JavaScript code that is compiled from TypeScript will once again be missing any type-annotations. I.e. TypeScript helps you with types at compile-time, but there is no TypeScript "runtime". You're just back to "basic" javascript at this point.